# Understanding functioning of 'this' in a context

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried my best to understand this but cannot understand why **'this'** is not working in first code but works in second code example.

**First** (this doesnt work here)

```
$('#' + ID).parent().siblings().each(function() {
    selectChildren();
});

function selectChildren() {
    $(this).children('.left-links-dashboard').css({
        'color': 'grey'
    });
    //this one doesn't work..why ????
}
```

Over here the selectChildren() function has an argument and when calling the function **this** is passed to function and it works..

**Second**

```
$('#' + ID).parent().siblings().each(function() {
    selectChildren(this);
});

function selectChildren(esd) {
    $(esd).children('.left-links-dashboard').css({
        'color': 'grey',
        'font-weight': '400'
    });
    $(esd).children('.left-links-dashboard').children('i').removeClass('fa-arrow-circle-right').addClass('fa-angle-right');

}
```

Have read through stackoverflow, MDN and other resources but couldn't understand why the second code example works. Any explanation would really help me. Thanks

Comment: Because in the second one your passing `this` as a parameter.  Otherwise `this` refers to the function selectChildren

Comment: Aside from the answer below you can also make the first example work by using [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), like this: `selectChildren.call(this);`

Comment: Keith. this is what I cannot understand. When  a parameter is passed to selectChildren() function, it works. But it doesn't work when called without this parameter. I am trying to understand how it works.

Comment: Rory. Yeah, i read recently call and apply. You are right i can use call. Its jut that i can't move ahead without understanding why its not working in first case.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the current function reference

But in your first code the `this` is in inside the wrapper `selectChildren()` since the function is invoked inside another function, 
if you want the first code to work you can do it like this

```
$('#' + ID).parent().siblings().each(selectChildren); 
// I removed the anonymouse function to set the reference of the jquery element directly to selectChildren function 

function selectChildren() {
    $(this).children('.left-links-dashboard').css({
        'color': 'grey'
    });
    //this one doesn't work..why ????
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in javascript is the context of owner of the function. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Your first example implies that the invoked function is owned by the `window` object. If you want to use your function in a "jquery way":

$(this).selectChildren()

then research writing jquery plugins: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: `If you want to use your function in a "jquery way": $(this).selectChildren()` For that to work the function would need to be entirely re-written as a plugin. There's easier and quicker ways to execute code under a given scope in jQuery without resorting to that.